# How to manage AWS CloudWatch per-instance alarms for instances created with Auto Scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I set up a per-instance CPUUtilization alarm on CloudWatch, which appears to require an instance ID.

1. How do you add a per-instance alarm on instances that have been created with auto scaling? I would not know the instance ID or even that the instance has been created.
2. If I create an alarm for the instance after it is created, when the instance is terminated, the alarm remains with "INSUFFICIENT DATA".

Comment: Probably with Lambda, iterating through instances available and maybe looking at the tags. You can do most things in AWS with Lambda, though it's not always the most efficient way, I haven't done much in this area so can't give you much advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a Lambda function through CloudWatch event rules to manage your alarms.

Create an event rule for the following autoscaling events:

- RunInstances
- TerminateInstances

Register your Lambda function as the target for these events, which fetches the InstanceId(s) from the event data and creates or deletes alarms accordingly.

Below is a sample event rule description for RunInstances event.

```
{
"source": [
    "aws.ec2"
],
"detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
],
"detail": {
    "eventSource": [
        "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
        "RunInstances"
    ],
    "userAgent": [
        "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

It is also possible to use [Lifecycle hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html), but CloudWatch events is a better fit for this use-case.